# WebAPI 2 Redirect

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I want to route mydomain.com/signin-microsoft to api/Account/ExternalLoginCallback

Any idea how to solve this problem ?

**Configuration**

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "MicrosoftOAuth",
            routeTemplate: "signin-microsoft",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "ExternalLoginCallback" });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null)
    {

    }
```

**UPDATE:**
For testing purposes, i have tried configuration:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/test-test")]
    public async Task ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null)
    {

    }
```

and it is working just fine.
As i am using OWIN with OAuth, it is probably related to MicrosoftOAuth provider.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use attribute routing for this. In your configuration:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Add this attribute to your ExternalLoginCallBack method:

```
[Route("signin-microsoft")]
```

Comment: We're going to need a little more than this, have you tried debugging your application? What causes this response?

Comment: Yes, i have debugged application with Fiddler, i think it is related to Microsoft OAuth provider